# iOS + Cocos2D: Simple Colission/Bounce (do I need box2d/chipmunk?)

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

So I am writing a simple game and need to do collision detection. Basically balls are going to bounce off each other as well as walls.

Do you think chipmunk/box2d would be overkill for this? Or can I just implement the algorithm myself?

Answer (score 2):

I'm a huge fan of Box2d so I'd recommend using that.  Your simple game may start of simple but if you ever want to do more then you are all setup.  Also, once you implement it and get the basics down you'll be amazed at how simple it is.  If you decide to go with Chipmunk though, I've heard a lot of good things about Space Manager (http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-spacemanager/) as far as being really easy to implement, but I have not used it myself.

Check out:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/457/intro-to-box2d-with-cocos2d-tutorial-bouncing-balls

for a great tutorial

Answer (score 0):

Detecting collisions of the balls will be easy. Making them bounce realistically is the difficult part. The more realism you want/need, the better off you will be using a physics engine.