# How to write a bouncing ball from scratch without cocos2d

Tags: ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

It is so easy to write some code to achieve the bouncing ball based on the open source project cocos2d,[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343988/ios-cocos2d-simple-colission-bounce-do-i-need-box2d-chipmunk) is the question.

So without cocos2d, how to implement this with the simplest code.

Comment: First of all, fuskaren was very kind to do all of that for you. In general, we prefer it if you actually try something first. whathaveyoutried.com.

Comment: that is what I really want before I tried with different approach.

Comment: In the answer provided by fuskaren, why is it not necessary to call `setNeedsDisplay()` from the `CADisplayLink` callback?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First you need to create a ball class. This class should have ivars for position, velocity, direction etc. 
It should also have some methods for when the ball needs to change direction, like hitTop, hitBottom, hitLeft, hitRight. It should also have a method for updating the position, to move it one step forward.
I also have a BallView so that I can use a image or just a color as the ball.

To make it move you need to have a gameloop in you view controller, there are many methods for doing that but the one I find easiest is CADisplayLink.

Here are some code if you have problems implementing it:

**Ball.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "MovingObjectView.h"

@interface MovingObject : NSObject

@property(nonatomic, retain) MovingObjectView *ball;

@property CGRect bounds;
@property CGPoint position;
@property CGPoint direction;
@property float velocity;

-(id)initWithBounds:(CGRect)b andPosition:(CGPoint)p;

-(BOOL)positionIsInsideRect;
-(void)update;

-(void)hitLeft;
-(void)hitRight;
-(void)hitTop;
-(void)hitBottom;

@end
```

**Ball.m**

```
#import "MovingObject.h"

@implementation MovingObject

-(id)initWithBounds:(CGRect)b andPosition:(CGPoint)p
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.bounds = b;
        self.position = p;
        self.direction = CGPointMake(1, 1);

        //Change the position to middle if position is outside bounds
        if (![self positionIsInsideRect]) {
            NSLog(@"Position changed to center");
            self.position = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2);
        }

        self.ball = [[[MovingObjectView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.position.x, self.position.y, 15, 15)]autorelease];
    }
    return self;
}

//checks if the balls position is correct
-(BOOL)positionIsInsideRect {
    if (self.position.x < self.bounds.origin.x || self.position.x > self.bounds.size.width || self.position.y < self.bounds.origin.y || self.position.y > self.bounds.size.height) {
        NSLog(@"Position is outside bounds");
        return NO;
    }else{
        return YES;
    }
}

//Call this method to move a ball
-(void)update {
    //Checks if the ball is outside bounds
    if (self.position.x-(self.ball.frame.size.width/2) <= self.bounds.origin.x) {
        [self hitLeft];
    }else if (self.position.x+(self.ball.frame.size.width/2) >= self.bounds.size.width){
        [self hitRight];
    }else if (self.position.y-(self.ball.frame.size.height/2) <= self.bounds.origin.y) {
        [self hitTop];
    }else if (self.position.y+(self.ball.frame.size.height/2) >= self.bounds.size.height){
        [self hitBottom];
    }

    //Updates the balls position
    CGPoint p = self.position;
    p.x += self.direction.x*self.velocity;
    p.y += self.direction.y*self.velocity;
    self.position = p;

    self.ball.center = self.position;
}

//Call this when the ball need to bounce
-(void)hitLeft
{
    NSLog(@"hitLeft");
    CGPoint d = self.direction;
    d.x = fabsf(self.direction.x);
    self.direction = d;
}

-(void)hitRight
{
    NSLog(@"hitRight");
    CGPoint d = self.direction;
    d.x = -fabsf(self.direction.x);
    self.direction = d;
}

-(void)hitTop
{
    NSLog(@"hitTop");
    CGPoint d = self.direction;
    d.y = fabsf(self.direction.y);
    self.direction = d;
}

-(void)hitBottom
{
    NSLog(@"hitBottom");
    CGPoint d = self.direction;
    d.y = -fabsf(self.direction.y);
    self.direction = d;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

**BallView.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MovingObjectView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImage *img;

@end
```

**BallView.m**

```
#import "MovingObjectView.h"

@implementation MovingObjectView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}


// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if (self.img == nil) {
        CGRect bounds = [self bounds];
        [[UIColor blackColor]set];
        UIRectFill(bounds);
    }else {
        CGRect bounds = [self bounds];
        [[UIColor whiteColor]set];
        UIRectFill(bounds);
        [self.img drawInRect:rect];
    }
}

@end
```

Then finally in the viewcontroller you need this:

**ViewController**

In viewdidload:

```
self.displayLink = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(gameLoop)];
[self.displayLink addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
```

Then add this method:

```
-(void)gameLoop
{   
    //Updates the balls position
    [self.movingBall update];

    //Here you could add your collision detection code
}
```

Comment: thanks very much ! that is what I really want. several hours' waiting, the problem sovled and I will improve my idea later. thanks